# The NIntegrate cannot give a correct answer by Mathematica

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, special-functions

Here I want to compute this integral using the Mathematica
$$\int_0^\infty \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}s^{\frac{1}{2}+2} \exp (-s) \cos \left(\frac{f}{2}\right) \exp (-i k s) \exp \left(-\frac{\sqrt{8 s u}}{\cos \left(\frac{f}{2}\right)}\right)\; df\, ds$$

For simplicity, I use $w$ as the upper limit of the integral with respect to $s$.

Thus, we have the following code by *Mathematica*:

```
Gamm[k_, u_] :=2/(15*Sqrt[Pi])*
  NIntegrate[Exp[-I*k*s]*s^(1/2+2)*
    Exp[-s]*Cos[f/2]*Exp[-Sqrt[8*s*u]/Cos[f/2]],
  {f, -Pi, Pi}, {s, 0, w}];
Table[Gamm[0, u], {u, 0, 0.1, 0.001}]
```

IF I choose **`w = 10`**,
*Mathematica* gives:

```
Table[Gamm[0, u], {u, 0, 0.1, 0.001}]
(*  {0.99443, 0.789459, 0.722113, 0.675455, 0.639067, 0.609022,
     0.58335, 0.560903, 0.540948, 0.522983, 0.506647}  *)
```

When I choose **`w = 10^6`**,
the above integral yields

```
Table[Gamm[0, u], {u, 0, 0.1, 0.001}]
(*  {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}  *)
```

Clearly, the integral is not zero. How to solve this problem? It seems that there is something wrong.

Any suggestion is helpful! Thanks!

Comment: If the question is no clear, please give me a comment.

Comment: Your code dosen't work for me ?

Comment: You need spaces between variables: `su` should be `s u` and `Iks` should be `I k s` etc.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk   now the code is fine.  In the previous case, I copy this as text. It is not good.

Comment: Instead of integrating `{s, 0, 1000000}`, include one or more intermediate points, as `{s, 20, 1000, 1000000}`.

Comment: @LouisB  Thanks your answer.  According to suggestion, it works. But if the intermediate points is not good, for example  {s, 0, 0.1, 10^6},  the results of the Mathematica is also not good.  How can we solve this more effectively?

Comment: Please read the description of the tag [tag:bugs], which has a reserved usage.

Comment: Don't you get error messages for `w = 10^6`?  How did you address them?  Why are they mentioned in the question?

Comment: This not a Riemann Integral, right?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is a Riemann integral or not. But our work is related to fractional derivatives.  @niloderoock

Comment: Thanks, I will not use tag bug anymore.   @MichaelE2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following problem is hidden by `NIntegrate`, but which is one of the common sources of the `NIntegrate::izero` message you get from the OP's code.

```
Exp[-I*k*s]*s^(1/2 + 2)*Exp[-s]*Cos[f/2]*
   Exp[-Sqrt[8*s*u]/Cos[f/2]] /.
 {k -> 0, u -> 0.1} /. {f -> 1., s -> 1000.}
```

> General::munfl: Exp[-1032.23] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

> ```
> (*  0.  *)
> ```

**Tip:** You should make some sort of exploration of the integrand when a numerical integral misbehaves.  The two first things would be to evaluate it at a typical point in the integration region and to plot it (if possible, i.e., if it's a single- or two-variable function).

```
Gamm[k_, u_] := 
  2/(15*Sqrt[Pi])*
   NIntegrate[
    Exp[-I*k*s]*s^(1/2 + 2)*Exp[-s]*Cos[f/2]*
     Exp[-Sqrt[8*s*u]/Cos[f/2]], {f, -Pi, Pi}, {s, 0, w}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 32];

Block[{w = 10^6},
 Table[Gamm[0, u], {u, 0, 1/10, 1/100}]
 ]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

> NIntegrate::slwcon: ....

```
(*
  {1.0000000000626411805661509309408, 
   0.50827294088807703485723248346197, 
   ...
   0.16444683406465457205578964022320, 
   0.15112873347891652231157354357054}
*)
```

The message is just a warning.

I'm not sure why the integral in TeX in the OP is not the integral being coded:

```
Block[{w = Infinity},
 Table[Gamm[0, u], {u, 0, 1/10, 1/100}]
 ]
(*
  {0.99999999998679967008116173695908,
   0.50827294069524647486336322647360, 
   ...
   0.16444683409559630424360181571660,
   0.15112873348047743265847037936301}
*)
```